# Why isn't curator recovering when zookeeper is back online?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have a `CuratorFramework` client (v5.1.0) running against a Zookeeper server (v3.7.0). If the
Zookeeper server is shutdown while the client is connected to it I can see connection states
(with a `ConnectionStateListener`) of `SUSPENDED` and then `LOST` and then nothing more even
when the server comes back online.

This feels like a very standard use case and that I must be missing something silly, but I can never
get the client to connect again once the server is online.

I have done some google searching and found nothing useful about how to handle recovery after a LOST state.

I have a [self-contained example](https://github.com/cjstehno/curator-recovery) of what I am doing with
the example code in the
[CuratorRecoveryTest](https://github.com/cjstehno/curator-recovery/blob/master/src/test/java/demo/CuratorRecoveryTest.java) class
(run in IDE rather than maven). The meat of it is (extracted from the test class):

```java
// setup the server and client
server = new TestingServer();

client = newClient(server.getConnectString(), 60000, 15000, new RetryNTimes(1, 250));
client.start();
client.blockUntilConnected();
            
// add the listener
final var stateListener = new StateListener();
stateListener.stateChanged(client, CONNECTED);

// register the listener
client.getConnectionStateListenable().addListener(stateListener);

// verify connection
assertTrue(client.getZookeeperClient().isConnected());

// let things settle
nap(3, "initial settling");

// stop zk
stopServer();
log.info(">>>>>>>>>> STOPPED ZK SERVER");

// let it bake
nap(3, "letting things bake");

// ensure disconnected
assertFalse(client.getZookeeperClient().isConnected());

nap(3, "disconnecting");

// start zk
server.start();
log.info(">>>>>>>>>> STARTED ZK SERVER");

await().atMost(5, MINUTES).until(() -> stateListener.getCurrentState() == CONNECTED || stateListener.getCurrentState() == RECONNECTED);

// NOTE: it never gets here - no state changes after LOST

assertTrue(client.getZookeeperClient().isConnected());
```

When this is run I get the following output:

```
[Thread-0] INFO org.apache.curator.test.TestingZooKeeperMain - Starting server
[Thread-0] WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory - maxCnxns is not configured, using default value 0.
[main] INFO org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
[main] INFO org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Default schema
[main] WARN demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - CONNECTION-STATE-CHANGE: null --> CONNECTED
[main] DEBUG demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - Taking a 3s nap for initial settling...
[main] DEBUG demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - Done napping for initial settling...
[Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - CONNECTION-STATE-CHANGE: CONNECTED --> SUSPENDED
[main] INFO demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - >>>>>>>>>> STOPPED ZK SERVER
[main] DEBUG demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - Taking a 3s nap for letting things bake...
[main] DEBUG demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - Done napping for letting things bake...
[main] DEBUG demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - Taking a 3s nap for disconnecting...
[main] DEBUG demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - Done napping for disconnecting...
[main] INFO demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - >>>>>>>>>> STARTED ZK SERVER
[Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - Session timeout has elapsed while SUSPENDED. Injecting a session expiration. Elapsed ms: 20009. Adjusted session timeout ms: 20000
[main-EventThread] WARN org.apache.curator.ConnectionState - Session expired event received
[Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN demo.CuratorRecoveryTest - CONNECTION-STATE-CHANGE: SUSPENDED --> LOST
```

which then fails when the waiting condition never happens.

> NOTE: This happens on an older version combination of Curator and Zookeeper as well, so this is not a "bleeding edge" issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce with your github code. But if I remove the `server.close`, and replace your `start` with a `restart`, it causes the client to reconnect successfully. Probably `server.close` means the test server cannot be started again.

Perhaps add your original in-production stacktrace to your question? I am experiencing your issue, and suspect it's due to a bug in the curator's use of the `ZooKeeper.updateServerList` method.

Comment: This test is meant to simulate a zookeeper server going down (possibly for a few minutes) and then starting back up - not sure if your suggested changes still reflect that. There is not really a stacktrace per se, but just a stream of "unable to connect" messages in the log. I can reproduce it with an actual server, but it's hard to present that in a test. I'll have to look into that method you mentioned.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems that this is a bit of a red herring. The `TestingServer` does not behave in the same manner as a real server when it is killed and started again. When I try the same scenario against a standard ZK server it reconnects fine after LOST. My issue must be coming from my service code somewhere. I will probably close out this question.

Comment: UPDATE-2: I just had a thought that the reason the testing server is not working for me is that it probably starts up the second time on a different port than the first - I will have to look into this and post an update or close the question.

Comment: I experienced this behavior as well. I didn't find the root cause, but I did something different in the test: instead of stopping and starting one TestingServer instance, I stopped the first instance and created a second instance with the same port as the first to simulate ZooKeeper coming back online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and concluded that the curator appears to reuse obsolete IPs when the zookeeper server is restarted.

The approach outlined in [this ticket](https://github.com/pravega/pravega/issues/3651) worked for me. In particular, [this commit](https://github.com/pravega/pravega/pull/3789/commits/cb41e26bb9154bc80671a12cf347c135d56d1ba6) which adds a custom `ZookeeperFactory` which does not reuse the previous, out-of-date IP, but instead uses the original non-resolved hostname.

In brief, when creating the curator, assign a custom ZookeeperFactory

```
CuratorFramework zkClient = CuratorFrameworkFactory
    .builder()
...
    .zookeeperFactory(new ZKClientFactory())
```

where this `ZKClientFactory` creates a new `Zookeeper` from a cached `connectString`.